# How can I define a variable in a TCSH script that will not be exported to the process which invoked it?

Tags: scripting, command-line-interface

I know that in KSH, if I write `export A=B` the process which invoked my script can evaluate `${A}`, and if I write `A=B`, then `${A}` will have no value outside of my script.

How can this be done in `TCSH`? I only know of the style: `setenv A B` to set value for variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell variables can be set via the `set` command in `(t)csh`.

```
set variable=value
```

Comment: Thanks - that indeed what I was looking for.
Is `Shell variables` the official terminology in documentation?

Comment: Yes. Those variables are called `shell variables`. The other kind of variables (those to be set using `setenv`) are `environment variables`.